# Pandas. Отношение максимальной дисперсии к минимальной

Tags: python, pandas

Прохожу курс Python для анализа данных и никак не могу понять в чем ошибка в решении.

**Суть задачи**:
Создайте новый столбец - mcc_code+tr_type, сконкатенировав значения из соответствующих столбцов. (*)
Оставьте только наблюдения с отрицательным значением amount. Посчитайте дисперсию по категориям получившегося столбца mcc_code+tr_type, в которых количество наблюдений >= 10.
Определите отношение максимальной дисперсии к минимальной.
Выведите ответ в виде вещественного числа, округлённого до ближайшего целого в формате "123456" без дробной части.

Пояснения:
(*) Для конкатенации значений в столбцах можно использовать метод .astype(str) для серии и складывать соответствующие серии. Либо же применять apply к строкам датафрейма, прописывая логику преобразования и конкатенации значений внутри.

(**) Для одновременного подсчета количества наблюдений и дисперсии по категориям можно воспользоваться функцией .agg()

**Исходные данны**е:

[ссылка на файлы для расчетов](https://dropmefiles.com/7OHLV)

**Мое решение задачи**:
вначале требуется объединить 4 таблицы с разными данными, но с общими столбцами

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\akuma\Documents\Jupiter_Anaconda\transactions.csv',
           sep=',', nrows=1000000)
types = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\akuma\Documents\Jupiter_Anaconda\types.csv',
           sep=';')
mcc_codes = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\akuma\Documents\Jupiter_Anaconda\tr_mcc_codes.csv',
           sep=';')
train = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\akuma\Documents\Jupiter_Anaconda\gender_train.csv',
           sep=',')
df_1 = df.merge(types, how='inner')
df_2 = df_1.merge(mcc_codes, how='inner')
df_3 = df_2.merge(train, how='left') # базовая таблица
```

После получения базовой таблицы примерно такого содержания, с ней уже работаем по задаче.

[image: готовая таблица]
извините что картинка, не разобрался как вставлять сюда датафрейм.

```
df_3['mcc_code+tr_type'] = df_3[['mcc_code','tr_type']]
df_3.info()
df_3.query('amount < 0').groupby(['mcc_code+tr_type'])['amount'] \
                                  .agg(['count', 'var']) \
                                  .query('count >= 10')['var'] \
                                  .agg(lambda x: round(max(x) / min(x)))
```

**появляется ошибка при объединении столбцов mcc_code+tr_type**
, может где-то ошибку допустил?
Понимаю, что пишу код ещё плохо и мудрено )

Comment: слабо верится что команда `df_3['mcc_code+tr_type'] = df_3[['mcc_code','tr_type']]` - отработала без ошибок...

Comment: Ален, Добрый день. Тоже прохожу курс. Если Питон еще как то знала( начала недавно изучать после Делфи) то тут с pandas впервые столкнулась и пока не сильно разобралась. С горем пополам Homework_1 сдала . сейчас с Homework_2 полный завал. Если есть возможность, поделись известными решениями(кодом-решением) Homework_2 пожалуйста. margarita007@sibmail.com . поможет разобраться

Comment: @MaxU почему? может быть ошибка в объединении через это команду? посоветуйте другую.

Comment: @Alen, потому что в этой команде вы пытаетесь создать новый столбец и присвоить ему фрейм сразу с двумя столбцами. Если я правильно понимаю так сделать не получится. Чтобы что-то посоветовать, надо понимать вопрос, а я его не очень понимаю. С чем конкретно у вас возникли затруднения?

Comment: @MaxU в задаче предлагается "Создайте новый столбец - mcc_code+tr_type, сконкатенировав значения из соответствующих столбцов." Я не совсем понял как можно сконкатенировать, искал в интернете, понял что можно через merge. Может из-за неправильной команды объединения двух столбцов у меня неверный итоговый ответ?

Comment: немного отредактировал текст вопроса чтобы было понятнее

Answer (score 1):

Как делать конкатенцию указано в пояснении.

> Пояснения: (*) Для конкатенации значений в столбцах можно использовать
> метод .astype(str) для серии и складывать соответствующие серии. Либо
> же применять apply к строкам датафрейма, прописывая логику
> преобразования и конкатенации значений внутри.

```
df_3['mcc_code+tr_type'] = df_3['mcc_code'].astype(str)+df_3['tr_type'].astype
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
df["mcc_code+tr_type"] = df["mcc_code"].astype(str) + df["tr_type"].astype(str)
res = (df
       .query("amount < 0")
       .groupby("mcc_code+tr_type")
       ["amount"]
       .agg(lambda x: x.var()**2 if len(x)>=10 else np.nan).dropna())
ratio = round(res.max() / res.min())
```

Answer (score 0):

Для разннообразия решений:

```
df['mcc_code+tr_type'] = df.mcc_code.map(str) + df.tr_type.map(str)
df = df[['mcc_code+tr_type', 'amount']][df.amount < 0]
fltr = lambda group_df: len(group_df['amount']) >= 10
amount = (df.groupby('mcc_code+tr_type').filter(fltr) 
            .groupby('mcc_code+tr_type').var()).amount  
np.rint( amount.max() / amount.min()).astype(int)
```

p.s.:
Решение @MaxU элегантно, но дисперсия это просто var() (!=var()**2)
Из описания перого задания (ну и в целом ищи std vs var):
"Дисперсия рассчитывается с помощью функции из библиотеки numpy:
np.var( , ddof=0) или встроенной в python функции: .var(ddof=1)",
хотя и они ошиблись если планировали тот же результат
np.var(df.s, ddof=0) != df.s.var(ddof=1)
[numpy и pandas имеют разные значения ddof по умолчанию (на сегодя),
но разница в методике незначительна]